# Data save with phpfreechat

Tags: php, chat, joomla3.0

I am facing a problem related to data saved.
I use PHPFreeChat Method to Mysql. so it will save chat history into my database.
But if I look into my database, I can find some record's data automatically has been removed. I don't know why that is. I want to stop this automatic data removal.

Please, can anyone help me find some solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you're using? http://www.phpfreechat.net/

Comment: sorry for the delay reply..yes Lodder.

Comment: There might be an auto-prune function that basically removes some of the data atfer a certain amount of time. However it's probably best you contact the developers of the chat system

Comment: Hi Lodder,thanks ur advise. I just created trigger on the table for insert that copies it over to chat table.this is not perfect solution.but it worked for me.